# Issue with rematch in bash regex

Tags: bash

I have a file like below:

```
0.000  -0.001 0.017         (F) -0.001 af mclk   rdctrlp1/timer/ircb%clk {ec0crb0o2ab1n03x5}
0.027  0.026  0.012  0.002  (F) 0.026 af mclk    rdctrlp1/timer/ircb%clkout {ec0crb0o2ab1n03x5} ORGATE
0.001  0.027  0.013         (F) 0.027 af mclk    rdctrlp1/timer/iclkout_inv%clk {ec0cinv00ab1n12x5}
0.011  0.037  0.010  0.007  (R) 0.037 af mclk    rdctrlp1/timer/iclkout_inv%clkout {ec0cinv00ab1n12x5} NOTGATE
0.001  0.038  0.010         (R) 0.038 af mclk    rdctrlp1/clksdlgen/i01%clk {ec0ceb000ab2n02x4}
0.026  0.064  0.005  0.001  (R) 0.064 af mclk    rdctrlp1/clksdlgen/i01%clkout {ec0ceb000ab2n02x4} BUFFER
0.000  0.064  0.006         (R) 0.064 af mclk    rdctrlp1/clksdlgen/i0invd%clk {ec0cinv00ab2n02x5}
0.006  0.070  0.005  0.001  (F) 0.070 af mclk    rdctrlp1/clksdlgen/i0invd%clkout {ec0cinv00ab2n02x5} NOTGATE
0.000  0.070  0.005         (F) 0.070 af mclk    rdctrlp1/clksdlgen/inand0dft%clk {ec0cnan02ab3n02x5}
0.011  0.081  0.012  0.002  (R) 0.081 af mclk    rdctrlp1/clksdlgen/inand0dft%clkout {ec0cnan02ab3n02x5} NANDGATE
```

I am using this below code for matching these kind of lines and processing further:

```
pattern="^\s+(-?\d(\.\d+)?)\s+(-?\d(\.\d+)?).+?\((R|F)\).+?(a|b)(.)\s"

if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]
then
    arc_type="${BASH_REMATCH[7]}"_"${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
    delay="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

It doesn't work, not sure why. Below is a regex that works fine in the same script:

```
if  [[ $line =~ "#(.+?)\s,\s.+?ip%(.+?)\s->>\s.+?ip%(.+?)\s,\s" ]]
```

Comment: can you describe the final goal, it's about filtering out the lines?

Comment: The file contains lot of other lines. So, once this pattern is found, I need to find sum of the numbers in first field, on odd and even rows separately.
And, from the regex, I need to re use \1 \5 and \7 occurrences, that's why the grouping

Comment: Are there spaces at the beginning of every line? The example from the file doesn't look like it, but your pattern seems to assume there are.

Comment: Sorry, spaces are there. When I copied I lost it.

Also the arc_type assignment, I want it to be \7_\5, Not sure if I have done it the correct way here

Comment: I don't immediately see a match for `(a|b)(.)\s`.

Comment: It has match. this can be af mclk or ar mclk or bf mclk or br mclk. I need that "r" of "f"
This regex will match these lines, but it doesn't when ran with bash

Comment: Hi All, Is  there a way to do this in bash itself as asked, or using Perl is the only solution?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I understand bash was removing the beginning spaces.
Also, instead of \d I tired [0-9], this works.